Movie about a guy in the forest fighting some bikers
This movie is from the 90s. IIRC it is set in some sort of forest. The plot is about a family that gets killed by some bikers, I can't remember the reason, and the only survivor is a guy (very young). Then he finds an old man that teaches him how to survive and fight back to the bikers.
I clearly recall one scene where the kid wakes up to the song "California Dreaming" playing on his Walkman.
Edit:
I am not completely sure but I recall the guy using bow and arrows as weapons. 

I found it, the name of the movie is "Quiet Cool" and it stars James Remar. 

Can you offer some explanation as to why this answers the question?  Thank you :)
